# How to apply logarithmic scale in graph in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph, logarithm

I am new to JavaScript. Here I am plotting a graph. Since the values are very high the graph looks mess. So I would like to apply logarithmic scale in x axis and y axis. Could you please advice me how to do that in JavaScript? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Math.log() method to calculate the log base e of a number. I am assuming that you have an array of numbers for X axis and Y axis. Call Math.log() method in a for loop for all the elements present in the array for X and Y axis and plot them in a graph. I believe you already have code for plotting arrays on a graph. 
For more information on Math.log() method, refer to this document: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log